# How do I json_encode data from database

Tags: php

So this is my php code which gets images from database

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '123456789', 'demo');

  if ($conn->connect_error) {
  echo("Connection failed. " . $conn->connect_error)."</br>";
  }

mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
$output= array();

if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * from Gallery ORDER BY Image_ID DESC")) {
   while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
     $output[]=($row);
   }
}else{
 echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
}
echo json_encode($output);
echo json_last_error_msg();
      $conn->close();

?>
```

The problem is it's not json encode the array. and the error message I get is "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded".I don't understand most of the solutions i found and whatever solutions i thought I understood are not working. what exact code should I implement to fix this?

Comment: Why do you have parenthesis around `$row` here `$output[]=($row);`? I'm not saying it's wrong, I've just never seen it before. Also, can you provide a small example of the array output that gives you the error?

Comment: Can you post the `$output` array data, may be it is not well formed or have some values with special characters  `json_encode` cant handle

Comment: The array contains an image id and the image and when I echo the both of them i do get the image data. Encoding it is the problem. I dont know how I can show you the array data.

Comment: As for the parenthesis i put that there when i was trying out one of the solutions given to me. Doesnt affect thr code at all

Comment: I found out what was wrong. the images in the database where added via phpmyadmin meaning they wer not encoded to base 64. well that is what I think anyway. So I created a code that encodes then uploads the images, allowing me to json encode when retrieving. Thank you anyway.And if you have a better explanation of why this worked please to explain....